# Script called in crontab every hour keeps sending emails at pi@raspberrypi

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, bash, sendemail

I'm on ubuntu mate 16.04.3 LTS, I'm trying to send an email every hour (with crontab) with the IP of my Pi 3 and other details.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/pi/Desktop/myIP.txt"
nowip=$(wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain)
mailtosend="$nowip"
if [ -e "$file" ]
then
 #file exists
 echo "File Exists"
 fileip=$(head -n 1 $file)
 echo "$nowip VS $fileip"
 if [ "$nowip" == "$fileip" ]
 then
     echo "IPs Are The Same"
     #saved ip is the same as the actual ip
     echo $nowip > $file
 else
     echo "IP Changed"
     #saved ip is different from the actual ip
     echo "Replacing $fileip With $nowip Into $file And Sending It Via Email In This Format\n$mailtosend"
     echo $nowip > $file
     echo -e $mailtosend | mail -s "IP $nowip" my@hotmail.it
 fi
else
    echo "File Doesn't Exists"
    #file doesn't exist
    echo  "Writing IP $nowip Into $file And Sending It Via Email In This Format\n$mailtosend"
 echo $nowip > $file
 echo -e $mailtosend | mail -s "IP $nowip" my@hotmail.it
fi
```

This is my `ssmtp.conf` file:

```
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=postmaster

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
#mailhub=mail
mailhub= smtp.gmail.com:587
# Where will the mail seem to come from?
#rewriteDomain=

# The full hostname
hostname=raspberrypi

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES

AuthUser=my@gmail.com
AuthPass=mypassword
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

If I do `bash sendIP.sh` it doesn't give me any error but if it's executed as a cronjob my@gmail.com receives this email:

[image]

EDIT: crontab entry

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 */1 * * * bash /home/pi/Desktop/sendIP.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Try to change "#rewriteDomain=" to "rewriteDomain=gmail.com"

Comment: Can please also post the crontab entry you are using to start your script? [Edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/71368/edit) your question to add it.

Comment: This could be needed: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was already [answered on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84340):

> Cron will attempt to send an email with any output that may have
>   occurred when the command was run. From cron's man page:
>
> > When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of the crontab (or to the user specified in the MAILTO environment variable
> >     in the crontab, if such exists). Any job output can also be sent to
> >     syslog by using the -s option.
>
> So to disable it for a specific crontab entry just capture all of the
>   commands output and either direct it to a file or to `/dev/null`.
>
> ```
> 30 * * * * notBraiamsBackup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
> ```

Alternatively, you can also set the `MAILTO` environment variable to an empty string by placing the following line at the beginning of your crontab file:

```
MAILTO=""
```